# Get id that starts with some string, inside a jQuery loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**The context:**

I need to get some dynamic ids that are inside a TD element, to pass it as a parameter and call an specific function.

I added a class (**.calcStartPrice**) to the TD, so that it helps me iterating inside its elements:

```
    var inputEl, eventStartPrice, exchangeRate, convertedStartPriceEl, currSymbol, decimalPlaces;
jQuery(".calcStartPrice").each(function (i,e) {
    jQuery(e).find('span, input').each(function (a,b) {
        console.info(b.id);
    });
});
```

When I run this code, I have the following ids:

```
eventStartPrice_S20_L10140
S20_L10140_startPrice
exchangeRate_S20_L10140
curSymbol_S20_L10140
decPlaces_S20_L10140
converted_StartPrice_S20_L10140
```

Now, what I want to do is to check whether the id starts with eventStartPrice, for example, so that I'll attribute the id to a variable.

**What I tried:**

```
var eventStartPrice;
jQuery(".calcStartPrice").each(function (i,e) {
    jQuery(e).find('span, input').each(function (a,b) {
        //console.info(b.id);
        if (jQuery(b[id^="eventStartPrice"])) { //this is wrong!!!
            eventStartPrice = b.id;
            console.info(eventStartPrice);
        }
    });
});
```

But it didn't work... 
How can I check inside that second iteration if the id starts with some string?

Comment: `if(jQuery(b).is('[id^="eventStartPrice"]'))` ???

Comment: try if(b.id.split('_')[0]=='eventStartPrice')

Comment: What you want to do with `eventStartPrice`? Because you are reaffecting value each time condition is reach. BTW, i guess you don't need any kind of nested loop here

Comment: you could try this too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace :

```
if (jQuery(b[id^="eventStartPrice"])) { //this is wrong!!!
```

With :

```
if (/^eventStartPrice/.test(b.id)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(b).is("[id^='eventStartPrice']")
```

basically, b is not a normal object, you need to wrap it into a jQuery object so that you can perform operations on it. Or, more accurately, you're trying to access b as a jQuery object when it isn't.

Comment: What, you mean the $? I usually default to it ;)

Comment: i'm using jQuery because the project has legacy code and it was already using $ for other proposals, so I have to call jQuery to avoid having problems

Comment: No worries, whatever works for ya :)
Could always have fun with it and do var $kittens = jQuery; :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp :

```
if (b.id.match(/^eventStartPrice/)))
```

Comment: This would probably work too, but why use regexp when you can make jQuery do it for you?

Comment: @Zarazthuztra Because it is faster?

Comment: Based on what metrics? I'm honestly curious because I'd like to know for future reference. My rule of thumb is to not use regex's unless absolutely necessary, as they are typically not the fastest way of checking a string, especially when sizzler is highly optimized for DOM searches. http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Comment: I suspect the metric he's using is the number of keystrokes needed to type in the source code.

Comment: Here's the proof : http://jsperf.com/test-regexp-vs-js1. That is because jQuery init function use a regexp (https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L139). Then, if you are using jquery, you do 2 unnecessary function call, 1 when calling jQuery (wich also call numerous function) and one when calling `.is()`. Accessing an attribute (`id`) is faster than accessing a function. Also, im pretty sure `.match` is faster than `.querySelector` (that'S what jQuery use). Lastly, jQuery is javascript. Pure javascript will be faster than jQuery (if well coded).

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery split method

```
id_val = b.id
name = id_val.split('_');
```

Now `name[0]` will contain characters before '_'.
You can easily compare it using if statement

```
if(name[0] == "eventStartPrice")
{
......
}
```

Comment: That's a javascript method, not jQuery.

Comment: Yes.But its the simplest method as well.

Comment: I was not complaining about your way to do it, i was just correcting *"Use the jquery split method"*

Answer (score 0):

When u use jQuery each u get the dom element as this. If u then create a jQuery object of that u can apply all the magic to it. Thats what ur missing in ur code. So here is my sugestion how to rewrite ur function.

```
var eventStartPrice;
jQuery(".calcStartPrice").each(function (i,e) {
    jQuery(e).find('span, input').each(function (a,b) {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if ($this.is("[id^=eventStartPrice]")) {
            eventStartPrice = $this.attr("id");
            console.info(eventStartPrice);
        }
    });
});
```

U can test it out in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2YzKD/1/)

Comment: b and this are equivalent in this context, but you're absolutely correct :)