# What's faster in jQuery to find an element that matches a given set of rules, css or regexps?

Tags: jquery, regex, performance, jquery-selectors

A recent question got me thinking about this topic and how we handle CSS and jQuery selectors specifically (which uses the sizzler engine)

[Get id that starts with some string, inside a jQuery loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425773/get-id-that-starts-with-some-string-inside-a-jquery-loop/20425956?noredirect=1#comment30514366_20425956)

So I ask the community, let's say I have an issue such as the OP in that question, where I need to select an element based on the contents of an attribute, would it be faster to use a selector, or a regular expression? My general rule of thumb has always been to avoid regular expressions unless trying to process very complex strings with strict validation rules (emails, usernames, passwords, etc) and not for making sure a given attribute has a given value, as regular expressions tend to be slower based on their very nature, lots of research on this. [Some research material](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)

Using that question as an example, which is faster for conditional purposes:

```
$(b).is("[id^='eventStartPrice']")
```

or

```
if (b.id.match(/^eventStartPrice/)))
```

Assuming  b is some object with an id attribute starting with the attribute listed.

Comment: Fire up JSPerf and see

Comment: This is more of an "in general" question, not something that's case by case.

Comment: In general, performance is case by case.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding my question, and I'll be happy to edit the question to reflect this. In circumstances such as the one listed above, what tends to be faster? That's not to say I don't agree with you, because you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how "is" function from jQuery is built (it may add so overhead), so I would use match, a native JS function.

Comment: I can definitely see the point here, because yes, is() is a "black box" for our purposes in daily useage, however I don't think it's necessarily slower or faster than match. match() has to be implemented as well, same as is, and we don't know what that implementation is, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Even theoretically, this question isn't worth asking.  The whole point of a tool like jQuery is to free you from dealing with piddly-ass details like these.  Does it perform certain tasks more slowly than other technologies?  Maybe.  Does it matter?  Try it and see.

Whether it's regexes or jQuery or some other tool/framework/language, there will always be those who tell you not to use it because "it's slow."  Don't listen to them, listen to the thousands of people who are actually using it.  If the tool performed as badly as all that, they wouldn't be using it.

Comment: Just because everyone is doing it doesn't make it the best or right thing to do, and IMHO it's becoming a real problem that people are thinking that way. The question here is quite simple: Which is faster in a conditional?

Comment: Whatever their reason for choosing something like jQuery in the first place, if it turns out to be unusably slow, they'll switch to something else.  But whether they use regexes or CSS selectors is not going to affect the overall perceived performance.